# sql query in while loop returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi i have the following while loop, and the loop work well except for one value the following value is vag (output below) it returns me 'lamborghini' when it should return nothing

```
$sql2    = 'SELECT itempt_dim FROM dim WHERE id_dim = (SELECT iddimblg_rdim FROM rdim WHERE iddim_rdim =' . $id . ')';
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $nomeparente = $row2['itempt_dim'];
}
$volkswagen = mb_strtolower($nomeid) . ' = {text: {name:"' . mb_strtolower($nomeid) . '"},' . ' image: "img/' . mb_strtolower($nomeid) . '.png", parent: ' . mb_strtolower($nomeparente) . '},' . '<br>';
print_r($volkswagen);
```

output:

```
gallardo = {text: {name:"gallardo"}, image: "img/gallardo.png", parent: lamborghini},
espada = {text: {name:"espada"}, image: "img/espada.png", parent: lamborghini},
vag = {text: {name:"vag"}, image: "img/vag.png", parent: lamborghini (HERE!)},
volkswagen = {text: {name:"volkswagen"}, image: "img/volkswagen.png", parent: vag},
skoda = {text: {name:"skoda"}, image: "img/skoda.png", parent: vag},
seat = {text: {name:"seat"}, image: "img/seat.png", parent: vag},
```

Comment: Not your issue but please check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: sure i get what you are saying but that is not my point ... i just want to know how i can make the value display properly ...

Comment: Since you haven’t posted all the code we can’t help you.